# Why MySQL examines a full table row's even using where and indexing?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I was trying to optimize my SQL query and I encountered behavior that I can't understand.

Note: If I'm using JOIN also it examines all the records of table2

Version - 5.6

**QUERY 1 (Slow)**

```
-- Joining 2 table using subqueries. 
-- Even If I'm using JOIN also it examines all the records of table2
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    table1_id IN (SELECT 
            id
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            idx_column = 'value');
-- taking more than 20 seconds
```

Explain

```
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type|table          | type | possible_keys                     | key      | key_len | ref           | rows  | Extra                                                           |
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |SIMPLE     |table1         |ref   |PRIMARY,idx_column_idx             | PRIMARY  |4        |               |2      |Using index condition; Start temporary                           |
|1  |SIMPLE     |table2         |ALL   |NULL                               | NULL     | NULL    | NULL          |1129137|Using where; End temporary; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)|
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**QUERY 2 (Fast)**

```
-- Separately run the first subquery.
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    idx_column = 'value';

--- 
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table2
WHERE
    table1_id IN ({{Selected Id's from above query}}); 
-- taking less than a second
```

Explain

```
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type|table          | type | possible_keys                     | key      | key_len | ref           | rows  | Extra                                                           |
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |SIMPLE     |table2         |ref   |PRIMARY,table1_id                  | table1_id|48       | const         |2      |Using index condition                                            |
+---+-----------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------+----------+---------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Explain @scaisedge's Query

```
+---+------------+--------------------+------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |select_type | table              | type | possible_keys | key            | key_len |  ref | rows  | Extra                                             |
+---+------------+--------------------+------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |PRIMARY     |<derived2>          |ALL   |NULL           | NULL           |NULL     |NULL  |2      |NULL                                               |
|1  |PRIMARY     |table2              |ALL   |NULL           | NULL           |NULL     |NULL  |1129137|Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |    
|2  |DERIVED     |table1              |ref   |idx_column_IDX | idx_column_IDX | 33      | const|2      |Using index condition                              |
+---+------------+--------------------+------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For avoid full scan  you should use avoid the IN clause and use  a inner join on subquery

```
SELECT  table2.*
FROM  table2 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT   id
  FROM table1
  WHERE idx_column = 'value'
 ) t on t.id = table2.table1_id
```

Be sure that  table2.table1_id and table1.id have the same data type  ..

Comment: added Explain for your query. still, it examines all the records of table2.

Comment: have you cheked for performance ??? and are you sure you an index on  table2.table1_id ?   .. update your question and add  your table2 schema

Comment: which data type are table1.id and table2.table1_id ??

Comment: Yes, now its taking 2 seconds only. But I didn't understand, Can you explain more about.

Comment: @ramganesh  .. tipically an inner join is more performant respetc to an IN clause because  the IN clause is equivalente at a series or OR clause so the table is scanned  serveral time,  instead an inner join is execute juts one time  (the rows  are  just select all and joined  in a single phase) . The fact the index  is not use could be related  to many factor  .. the most common are the db engine " thinks  " that the better strategy is for primary index  .. or the two field involved  in join have different data type so this index is not involved ..hope is more clear

Comment: @for more information you could also try forcing the db to use the index  you thinks is better  (be sure for the matching datatype)  using  eg: ` FROM  table2 USE INDEX your_index_name `

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to turn `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN` or `EXISTS( SELECT 1 ...)`

```
SELECT  table2.*
    FROM  table2 
    JOIN  table1  ON table1.id = table2.table1_id
    WHERE table1.idx_column = 'value'
```

with indexes

```
table1:  (idx_column, id)
table2:  (table1_id)
```